# How to Add a anchor tag in email body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have opening my email and want to give one hyprlink in email body. for that i am using anchor tag, but it is not getting success. Can anyone tell what is going wrong here.

MyCode :

```
EmailLin : function(MyData){

    mailto:?subject=Hello :'+MyData.name+'&body=this is the name%0D%0A'+name+'&a=href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!%0D%0A'
}
```

Comment: Sir that question is around 10 year old. Even I am getting email with anchor tag. When I checked in view source this is bit like `<p class="Data"><span lang="EN-US"><a href="www.W3school.com">Vist School</a><o:p></o:p></span></p>` I just don't know how to place as per my javascript code.